# How to separate the delimited values in xml using an xslt coding

Tags: xslt

In our application we use xslt coding to convert the input xml to an output xml.
I am using the code below. But its only separating the first field before the semicolon.
Likewise I want to separate each value in output xml so that I can add the trailing spaces or the leading zeros to the fields required. SINO is our supplier number and the delimeted values are its values like price etc.

How can I separate each value and write in the same xml tag?

My Input:

```
<UserArea>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="SINO">852963;20210406;1520.00;1520.00;0.00;2789       852963        
                            2021 FAIRVIEW L</NameValue>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <NameValue name="SINO">TEST12345;20210406;1000.00;1000.00;0.00;2789       
                          TEST12345     2021 FAIRVIEW L</NameValue>
    </Property>
</UserArea>
```

The XSLT code I am trying is:

```
    <xsl:for-each 
               select="./*:CreditTransferPayment/*:PaymentTransaction/*:UserArea/*:Property/*:NameValue">
        <FGIACHFlat>
            <field1>
                <xsl:value-of select="'D'" />
                <xsl:call-template name="AddTrailingSpaces">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring(substring-before(. 
                               [@name='SINO'],';'),1)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="length" select="24" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:value-of select="(substring-after(.[@name='SINO'],';'),';')" />
            </field1>
        </FGIACHFlat>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Current output I am getting this way but don't want these way.

```
<FGIACHFlat> 
    <field1>D852963 20210406;1520.00;1520.00;0.00;2789 852963 2021 FAIRVIEW L ;</field1> 
</FGIACHFlat> 
<FGIACHFlat> 
    <field1>DTEST12345 20210406;1000.00;1000.00;0.00;2789 TEST12345 2021 FAIRVIEW L ;</field1> 
</FGIACHFlat>
```

Comment: Current output I am getting this way but don't want these way.   <FGIACHFlat>
   <field1>D852963                  20210406;1520.00;1520.00;0.00;2789       852963        2021 FAIRVIEW L ;</field1>
  </FGIACHFlat>
  <FGIACHFlat>
   <field1>DTEST12345               20210406;1000.00;1000.00;0.00;2789       TEST12345     2021 FAIRVIEW L ;</field1>
  </FGIACHFlat>

Comment: 1. Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question and add the expected result. 2. State which XSLT your processor you will be using.

Comment: Show us the output you want, please, and show also the code of the function `AddTrailingSpaces`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it working for now.
The xslt code I used is.
<xsl:for-each select="./*:CreditTransferPayment/*:PaymentTransaction/*:UserArea/*:Property/*:NameValue">


<xsl:variable name="stringToSplit" select=".[@name='SINO']" />
<xsl:variable name="separator" select="';'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="'D'" />
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize($stringToSplit, ';')">
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:call-template name="AddTrailingSpaces">
<xsl:with-param name="length" select="40" />
</xsl:call-template>


</xsl:for-each>

My Input is this:


852963                  ;                              20210406;000000001520.00;000000001520.00;000000000000.00;2789       852963        2021 FAIRVIEW L


TEST12345               ;                              20210406;000000001000.00;000000001000.00;000000000000.00;2789       TEST12345     2021 FAIRVIEW L


and the output I got as expected is this:

D852963                                                20210406000000001520.00000000001520.00000000000000.002789       852963        2021 FAIRVIEW L                                        
        
        
            DTEST12345                                             20210406000000001000.00000000001000.00000000000000.002789       TEST12345     2021 FAIRVIEW L

Some logic I have applied in our application and remaining through xslt coding.
I wanted to apply all the logic through xslt coding but I am new to xslt Coding.
For now its working for me.
Thank you